# I can't kill a port process

Tags: command-line, process, kill

I'm doing in Ubuntu 12

```
alex@ubuntu:~/folder$ lsof -t -i:3000
4469
alex@ubuntu:~/folder$ kill 4469
alex@ubuntu:~/folder$ lsof -t -i:3000
4469
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to specify Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10.

Comment: What is process 4469? Do you have permission to kill it? (try `sudo kill 4469`). Does that process respond to the signal sent to it? (try `sudo kill -9 4469`, as signal 9 is required to be acted upon.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
kill -9 4469
```

**or**

```
 fuser -k -n tcp 3000
```

3000 is the port number

**or** 
Use [killport](https://github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/blob/master/killport) command :

```
wget https://raw.github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/master/killport
killport 3000
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I found this useful to me as well. Combining the `lsof` command from your question and the `kill-9` from [Abdennour TOUMI's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368381/22949) into a much simpler and quicker one-line command would give the following:

```
kill -9 `lsof -t i:3000`
```

Inside of the two bactick (`` ` ``) keys, you have the `lsof -t i:3000` command from before, which gets the process on the port `3000`. Then, the `kill -9` command kills that process.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command. Replace 8000 with any other port that you want to free up.

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands.

> sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

This command will list down  Which process is listening on which port. (Replace your port number "10050" with port which you are going to kill.)

> sudo fuser -k **10050**/tcp